Variants of Grothendieck section conjecture
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety defined over a field $k$. We fix the following notations : $\overline{k}$ denotes the algebraic closure of the field $k$, $X_{\overline{k}}$ denotes the variety $X \times_{\mathrm{Spec}(k)} \mathrm{Spec}(\overline{k})$, $\pi_1(X)$ denotes first etale fundamental group with a fixed chosen base point $x_0 \in X(\overline{k})$.
Consider the following two sets

Set of $\pi_1(X_{\overline{k}})$-conjugacy classes of continuous sections of the fundamental sequence of etale fundamental groups $1 \rightarrow \pi_1(X_{\overline{k}}) \rightarrow \pi_1(X) \rightarrow \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k}/k) \rightarrow 1$.

Set of $k$-rational points of the variety, equivalently the set of sections of the structure map $X \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}(k)$.


Grothendieck section conjecture : The two sets described above are in bijection.
It is known the section conjecture does not hold in general. In particular, it is false for abelian varieties as shown in the article [M. Ciperiani, and J. Stix, Galois sections for abelian varieties over number fields]. I have the following questions
Q1. Suppose $X$ is an abelian variety and $k$ is a number field. Is it known that the set 1 is nonempty if and only if set 2 is nonempty? One direction, that is the injectivity, is known.
Q2. There seems to be a notion of etale homotopy fixed points(See for instance $\S$ 7.3 of [K. Cesnavicius, Obstructions to rational points via etale homotopy]) of the variety $X$ to be denoted by $X(hk)$(Here $h$ is for homotopy and $k$ is the ground field.). Suppose $X$ is an abelian variety and $k$ is a number field. Is it known that $X(hk)$ is nonempty if and only if the set 1 is nonempty? I believe this may be known for a $K(G, 1)$-space?
Q3. When $k = \mathbb{F}_q$, then Grothendieck section conjecture is known to be true as per Remark 2(4) of [M. Ciperiani, and J. Stix, Galois sections for abelian varieties over number fields]. What about other fields of characteristic $p$?
Thank you for your time.
